# Openid for app domain

Tags: openid, dns, for-loop

Hi i tried to enter into third party website using my google apps username & password. For that i used URL as https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=mydomain.com. I used this URL in stack overflow which directs to my domain's  login after i sign in it returns "Unable to login with your openid provider Errorr occured while sending a direct message or getting respose". I dont know how to step forward. Please Help me.

Thanks,
Sharun.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps for Domains OpenIDs are not standard OpenIDs.  They require proprietary handling, which StackOverflow does not currently support.